# SLF4J: The requested version 1.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6]

Tags: java

I was trying to write an excel file using **JXLS template file** and the corresponding JAR has dependency with **SLF4J 1.6** and resolve that during compilation. But another JAR has dependancy with **SLF4J 1.5.6** which also resolved for some other program for the same project. Also note that **SLF4J 1.5.6** is setting into the classpath. But when I am trying to execute JXLS program it is asking for SLF4J 1.6. In that scenario I am getting the above error.

Note the following points -

1. I am using Gradle as a build tool
2. I do not want to hamper the other processes which already running successfully using